# Strange drop in voltage on Eneloop AAA-Batteries

Tags: batteries, dc

I have a device in my flowerbox where I monitor soil moisture.
The device requires about 3.3 v (it's an Arduino pro mini with an ESP8266).

The device is running on 3 x AAA-batteries (should be 3.6 v)

The device runs a cycle of:

- Powering on ESP and Sensor
- Collecting sensor data
- Transmitting it via WiFi
- Powering off ESP and Sensor
- Sleeping 20 minutes

It's been running fine for almost 75 hours, then it started continuously restarting.

I measured the voltage of the batteries. They were 2.86 v.
Then I waited 5 minutes, measured the voltage. Now they were 3.1 v.
I thought this problem might be caused by low outside temperature. I stuck the batteries in the fridge for 20 minutes, then tested them.
They were 3.1 v.

**So question is:** How come the batteries voltage change that much?

Best regards
Frederik

Comment: The most common reason of batteries having lower voltage than printed on them is that *they are empty*

Comment: What is your average current consumption from your system?

Comment: sounds like the ESP is not actually sleeping; i get a weekend from 3 AAAs w/o deepsleep...

Comment: @dandavis, I'm turning the ESP off via a transistor.

Comment: if that's the case, your batteries should be lasting a lot longer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **They were 2.86 v. Then I waited 5 minutes, measured the voltage. Now they were 3.1 v.**

You may be seeing the [recovery effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_effect) as the energy in the batteries is depleted to a low level. When the load is removed, chemical or physical processes inside the battery (e.g. diffusion) allow it to recover partly.

I would use an analog input to monitor voltage and prevent restart looping.

I would not expect 3 x AAA cells to provide long term energy. At the least I would try to measure power consumption accurately for planning purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt feedback.
I was actually thinking about using an analog input for voltage measurements but I just hadn't come around to implementing it.
Can you recommend an alternative rechargeable power source?